# Grails read GORM Mapping

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm currently developing an AuditListener to create an History Entry for every DomainClass that I want to.

I created an AuditListener

class AuditingListener extends AbstractPersistenceEventListener {

```
public AuditingListener(final Datastore datastore){
    super(datastore)
}

@Override
protected void onPersistenceEvent(final AbstractPersistenceEvent event){
    switch(event.eventType){
        case EventType.PostInsert:
            onPostInsert(event as PostInsertEvent)
            break
        case EventType.PreUpdate:
            onPreUpdate(event as PreUpdateEvent)
            break
        case EventType.PreDelete:
            onPreDelete(event as PreDeleteEvent)
            break
    }
}

def onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event){
    Object domainClassObject = event.entityObject
    PersistentEntity entity = event.entity

    if(isAuditableEntity(domainClassObject)){ 
        try {
            GrailsDomainClass grailsDomainClass = getGrailsDomainClass(domainClassObject)
            Set<String> propertyNames = getPropertyNames(grailsDomainClass)
            if(propertyNames){
                Map properties = getPropertiesMap(propertyNames, domainClassObject, grailsDomainClass)
                createRevisionEntity(entity, grailsDomainClass, domainClassObject, properties)
            }

        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error "Could not found Audit domainClassObject Class of ${domainClassObject}", e
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to create the Method `createRevisionEntity` that should create the Revision for the current Entity. The Method should create an new Object called `RevisionEntity` and add dynamicly all the Properties of the current DomainClassObject. With that I would have an Revisioned Entity of any DomainClass I want, similiar to hibernate Envers.

I'm able to put dynamicly the properties to `RevisionEntity` but my Problem is that I didn't get the mapping Informations and put It in `RevisionEntity`.

Do U have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Have you looked at the audit-log plugin? It works well in our hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found a solution to geht the column Mapping:

```
    GrailsDomainBinder grailsDomainBinder = new GrailsDomainBinder()
    grailsDomainBinder.getMapping(domainClassObject.class).columns?.each{column ->
        println column
    }
```